# pass array from query to controller, codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have CodeIgniter question. How can I pass an array from view to controller?
I am not able to send data to controller from view by calling public function `sms()` on a button click.

Here is my code that doesn't work:

```
<script>
function send_sms() {
    var chkBoxArray = new Array();
        $(document).ready(function (e) {

        $('#table input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function () {
            var getRow = $(this).parents('tr');
            chkBoxArray.push(getRow.find('td:eq(9)').html());
        });

        alert(chkBoxArray);
        reload_table();
    });

    $.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo site_url('person/sms')?>",
        type: "POST",
        data: { 'arr': chkBoxArray },
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function (data) {
            // if success reload ajax table
            // alert(chkBoxArray);
            // reload_table();
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert('Error adding / update data');
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

Controller code :

```
public function sms() {
  $arr = $this->post('arr');
  foreach($arr as $ar) {
    echo $ar; // prints each element of the array.
  }
}
```

Comment: Not clear what specific problem is. *"doesn't work"* is a meaningless problem statement and doesn't suggest what part isn't working

Comment: Try first with `data: { arr: chkBoxArray },`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use : `$arr = $this->input->post('arr');` to retrieve post values, and if you expecting the returning result is a JSON type, then in server side you need to tweak the PHP code to return it by using `echo json_encode($arrayVariable);`, otherwise just omit `dataType:json` at AJAX properties.